# How to setup Shopping Cart Price Rule on a configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I am very confused on this thing. I have created a configurable product. The shopping cart rule does not work on the child SKU (simple product). Its only work with the Parent SKU (configurable product). In configurable product the child SKU is connected through the size attribute. The price rule seems to does not work on size attribute as well.

I want to create a buy one (get one free + postage charges) rule for a configurable product with three sizes. customer can choose any size size for the item and than choose any other size for the item to get the free one.

Someone please guide me in right direction. I am very confuse.

Comment: I am having this same issue. With configurable products, it does seem like only the Configurable product, not the simple products that make the configurable options are able to be used for price rules. :(

Answer (score 1):

Magento team did not fix issue with Catalog/Shopping rules based on attributes for configurable product on the current moment. Cos simple products are bound to configurable product is property of configurable product, but not attribute after binding process. However binding process based on simple attributes and it will be fixed.

I suppose, it take much time new feature implementation for catalog rules as was for tier prices.

But for shopping cart rules could be fixed simple.

Remeber, mentioned behavior does not work just for Action tab. Conditions tab attributes for configurable product works at the M1, but does not work for the Magento2 instance.

Example place for fixing M1: you can change just app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php class at the process() method:

```
if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
   continue;
}
```

There could be checked all Action for shopping cart rules. You can call and re-validate configurable children products in cycle.

Please, be aware, M2 release, sooner, will be with mentioned issues for configurable products.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to apply cart rules based on children attribute... but I'm not having success. How can I check if $item is configurable and than validate all children? Have made a module to extend Validator.php but if I check $item->isConfigurable() I get an error "Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::isConfigurable"

Comment: Can you give an example how to fix this "so we are capable" of applying discount actions on the products of parent/configurable attributes?